# Rails 4. Includes or SQL query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, scope, associations

Rails 4 + Postgresql.

Model #1 - Order
Model #2 - Product

**Association - HABTM**

Join table - **orders_products** 
I need take all orders for some day and show up in @orders.each

When in **@orders.each |order|** --> then a call **order.products** that create **N+1** problem

if i have 10 orders, it's mean 10 time one query will get data from DB

I tried that code and many modification of ... but it doesn't work...:

```
scope :orders_for_day, ->(date) { where(date: date).includes(:products) }
```

I can't figure out what is problem here.. Ok. Now i wanna use SQL.
Before make some code, i tested that query in psql name_of_db:

```
SELECT * FROM "orders" LEFT OUTER JOIN "orders_products" ON "orders_products"."order_id" = "orders"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "products" ON "products"."id" = "orders_products"."product_id" WHERE "orders"."date" = '2016-06-02'
```

and my results:

[image]

So,after this i wrote next code in Order model:

```
   scope :orders_for_day, -> (date) { find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM orders LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_products " \
                                  " ON orders_products.order_id = orders.id " \
                                  " LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.id = orders_products.product_id "\
                                  "WHERE orders.date = #{date}")}
```

in console i have that:

```
        Order Load (1.2ms)  SELECT * FROM orders LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_products ON orders_products.order_id = orders.id LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.id = orders_products.product_id WHERE orders.date = 2016-06-03
        PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: date = integer
        LINE 1: ...id = orders_products.product_id WHERE orders.date = 2016-06-...
                                                         ^
        HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.: SELECT * FROM orders LEFT OUTER JOIN orders_products  ON orders_products.order_id = orders.id  LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON products.id = orders_products.product_id WHERE orders.date = 2016-06-03
        Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
```

for sure, DB schema orders table:

```
create_table 'orders', force: true do |t|
   t.integer 'user_id'
   t.date    'date'
end
```

**EDIT #1 and EDIT #2**

when i use that scope:

```
scope :orders_for_day, ->(date) { where(date: date).includes(:products) }
```

that how i call products from view:

```
      - @orders.each do |order|
         %table.table.table-striped
           %tr
             %th Meal
             %th Price
           - order.products.each do |one_order|
           %tr
             %th=one_order.product_name
             %th=one_order.product_price
         .col-md-4.total-price-div
      %h5 Order coast: #{Order.current_order_coast(order.user_id, order.date)}
```

and my console:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can put "find_by_sql" inside of a scope , scope should return an activerecord relation . So move this out of the scope . But I think it's worth while to understand why the original scope wasn't working , what error did you get?

Comment: @Joel_Blum i added EDIT #2.  Need try that sql in method

Comment: Based on the console output, it looks like the N+1 issue is coming from querying orders by user. Are you sure you aren't running a query by user somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @Joel_Blum same error if i use method for that query,after:WHERE date=

Comment: @apod yes, it is. On the console..4 query for order.products and 4 query for price. I call on each order count each order price for... ( How optimize that stuff?

Comment: It might or might not have anything to do with it but 'date' is a reserved word in Rails http://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/date?page=2 , perhaps it's a bad name for a column

Comment: @Joel_Blum  i read that today, but think if it's working for psql console..think it will be fine for that query..also i agree it's a bad name.. should I make migration for change it?

Comment: It's fine for psql but you can't have Rails scopes calling a column named 'date' . Again , I'm not sure if that's your problem but it will become a problem soon , you should rename it to avoid trouble